# Repetitive Arrowheads

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

What change do I need to make here to make arrowheads appear at the rightmost point of *all* line segments instead of just the final one?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex]
 (0,0)--(1,0)
 (1.5,0)--(2.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw<first segment>; \draw<second segment>;`

Comment: @ Manuel  This is good if I have two line segments. But if I had, say, 30, and they needed to be blue, 1.3pt thick, 29% opacity, etc. I'd rather not write that out 30 times.

Comment: You can have workarounds with `scope` easily. Plus if you use a good text editor that lets you write at multiple places at the same time, it's completely easy. In any case, if Gonzalo Medina's answer works, that is, use `edge` instead of `--`, then that's probably the way to go ;)

Comment: What text editor allows you to write in multiple places at once? And what's `scope`?

Comment: `scope` is an environment from TikZ that lets you have a common configuration for everything that's inside. Text editors, there are a lot, Sublime Text and TextMate being two examples. Probably emacs and vim too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `edge`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[-latex]
 (0,0) edge (1,0)
 (1.5,0) edge (2.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your attempted

```
\draw[-latex]
 (0,0)--(1,0)
 (1.5,0)--(2.5,0);
```

doesn't work because `\draw[-latex]` instructs to place the arrow tip at the end of the path which is `(2.5,0)` (`\draw` builds a single path); on the other hand, using `edge` temporarily suspends the construction of the current path and a new path
is constructed and the arrow tip is added to each.

Comment: This looks like it works. I'll try it later today. Why, though, did my commands not work? And what is different about `\path` and `edge` from `\draw`?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Please see my updated answer; I added a little explanation; for further details on `edge` refer to the PGF manual.